# Convergence of Indicator function.

Tags: measure-theory

I was going through [Egorov's theorem on wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem)

It gives a example why should be  $\mu(A)<\infty $. Sequence of real valued indicator function is taken. It claims that the sequence: 
 $ f_n(x)=1_{[n,n+1]}(x) $ converges pointwise for $n\in N$ and $x\in\Re$.
I am not able to understand how it converges pointwise to $0$ ?

Comment: Oh thanks, just didn't strike me soon enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the pointwise convergence, you have to fix $x'\in \mathbb R$ and check that a *numerical limit* exists: in your case that $f_n(x') \to 0$. Clearly, *given* $x'$ you have that if $n>x'$ then $x'\notin[n,n+1]$ and hence $f_n(x') = 0$ for all $n>x'$, so that for any $x'$ you have $f_n(x')\to 0 $ - which is the pointwise convergence.